# Counting column values uniquely in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a column "Text" which holds values like :

```
Text
A
B
A B
A B C
A B C D
```

I want to visualize this column in Power BI in a bar chart but I want the values uniquely on the y axis and there count as the following:

So value "A" will have a count of 4 as "A" appears four times in all the rows similarly B will have a count of 4 and so on for C and D

I also want to ensure that on the y axis I just see the unique values like A, B , C and D.

So the final output should look like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

any ideas how can I achieve this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw31g.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get your data in Power Query like this:

[image]

Choose Split Column by Delimiter from the Transform ribbon and fill in as follows:

[image]

You'll get this.

[image]

Highlight the column and click Format - Trim.

[image]

Close & load.

In Power BI, place a stacked bar chart on the canvas. Drag your column to the field wells as follows:

[image]

Enable data labels.

[image]

Comment: That looks promising. By "Get your data in Power query" you mean I need to pull the same data again but just use my Text column? as I have already imported the data and my text column is there but I am sure I cannot transform this column in my original data model?

Comment: You can use the same query if you already have it. I don't know what your wider data model looks like but this is fairly common approach to reshape your data.

Comment: Just one quick question: what if I have a value like A B/C as one of my rows and I want to split this as A B and then C. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Yes, just add another step which splits by a different delimiter.

Comment: but wouldn't he process that you have suggested will split A and B into separate lines as they are separated by a space?

Comment: You can do two splits back to back as separate steps. First split by space and then split by forward slash.